# insert multiple record with store procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table

```
student(
  `sid` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sex` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `pob` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `dept` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `s_stat` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `i_stat` char(1) NOT NULL
)
```

and i have stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE insert(`sid` char(10),
  `name` varchar(100),
  `sex` char(1),
  `pob` varchar(70),
  `dob` date,
  `dept` char(5),
  `s_stat` char(1),
  `i_stat` char(1))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO student VALUES (sid, name, sex, pob, dob, dept, s_stat, i_stat);
END;
```

how to insert multiple record in table student using stored procedure.

i using this to insert record

```
    CALL insert 
('1814411831','RISKA','P','KADUNDU','1997/5/6','TI','A','B'),
('1814411684','ASTRIANI','P','SALULINO','2000/2/12','TI','A','B');
```

error

Comment: `insert` is a key word and should not be used as procedure table name

Comment: Not easily. Why not just call the procedure multiple times from your code?

Comment: @lucumt I assume he changed the name for demo purposes, and `insert` isn't the actual name of the table.

Comment: Its a bad idea to give parameters the same name as columns.

Comment: CALL insert ('1814411831','RISKA','P','KADUNDU','1997/5/6','TI','A','B'); 
only ada 1 record

Comment: CALL insert ('1814411831','RISKA','P','KADUNDU','1997/5/6','TI','A','B'),('1814411684','ASTRIANI','P','SALULINO','2000/2/12','TI','A','B');

error

Comment: No that's not possible, you will need multiple calls.